# How to pass `action` through `locale` string?

Tags: ember.js

here is my local string:

```
'CS2I.navbar.title' : 'Split Your Bills <a href="#" {{action keyFactLink}}>Link</a>',
```

After I am getting the template, there `action` disappears. how to pass the `action` through locale?

Because I am building the locale through dynamic
any help?

**UPDATE**
original link : `<a href="#" {{action 'keyFactLink'}}> {{t 'CS2I.here'}} </a>` works fine. I am doing a action to open a new page in  `keyFactLink`

Comment: What does your `keyFactLink` action return? Also, could you please post your locale `.json` file's content for this case.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç - see my update

Comment: As far as I know, passing actions through locale is not possible. In your case, if dynamic things are strings (such as link url), then both [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Translating-Text) and [ember-intl](https://github.com/ember-intl/ember-intl) provide enough base for passing parameters to locales.

Comment: this seems completely wrong? why do you need to include the action here? why not just have it in your template? why are you trying to include html in the local string?

Comment: This is a agreement in multi language, it requires to open different windows according to the language. The translation made here by dynamic